# Create Circular and Transparent Drawable XML Android

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I need to create a drawable with gray background and a circle inside with black border like this:

[image]

How can i do this in XML for an android app?

The center of this drawable **must be transparent**, not white. So i can create a layerDrawable composed by this xml drawable and another image drawable under it and set this layerDrawable to my imageView.

Hope i explained myself, Thanks!

Comment: You want also transparent color both for circle and rectangle right?

Comment: The rectangle must be gray in the corners, but the center of the circle (and the rectangle too) must be transparent. Finally, in that circle i'd like to see the drawable that i put as layer under this xml drawable

Comment: you cannot do it in xml, but can do it by extending Drawable class

Comment: Ok, what should I do in the extension?

Comment: I tried but it seems not possible in xml. you can try using a focusView :

https://medium.com/@rgomez/android-how-to-draw-an-overlay-with-a-transparent-hole-471af6cf3953

 or

simply create a  svg and use that